# Validate email field not empty Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to make validate if an email form field is not empty, of course I'm learning by making mistakes, but some explanation is needed from any of You Pro guys.

Heres wat I have and it's not working, all do it looks logical to me.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('regform').addEventListener("submit", function(e))
{
    if(document.querySelector("#mail")=='')
   {
      e.alert("You need to provide a valid email");
    } 
});
</script>
```

I'm kind of confused here.

This is the HTML:

```
<form class="login_form" id="regform" action="" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Your @ email" required>
  <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
</form>
```

Comment: Please also include the HTML form.

Comment: You don't need any JavaScript. Just set `required` on the `<input`.

Comment: I want to personalize the alert message, I could go with require that's an obvious one :-) but nooo!!!, why make it easy when we can go wild?

Comment: " why make it easy when we can go wild?" - _famous last words_

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('regform').addEventListener("submit", function(e))
 {
     if(document.querySelector("#mail").value == '')
     {
          e.alert("You need to provide a valid email");
     } 
}
</script>
```

get value from input text using `document.querySelector("#mail").value` and`document.querySelector("#mail")` only get element

Comment: It doesn't work, it doesn't display the alert.. :-(
I'm trying this and allso failing:

    <script>
          function validarmail(event){
            if(corro.value ==''){
            alert="No mail entered";
            event.preventDefault();
            }
          }
          const forma = document.getElementById("regform");
          const corro = document.getElementById("mail");
          forma.addEventListener("submit", validarmail);
          forma.addEventListener('submit', logSubmit);

    </script>